# Performing a multi-finger swipe using XCUITest

Tags: ios, xcode, automation, xctest, xcuitest

I am working with an app that supports swipe gestures with multi-fingers (2 finger down swipe, etc.), and would like to simulate this in XCUITests. I see that XCUIElement contains a bunch of functions like SwipeUp() and SwipeLeft(), however they all see to be for only single fingers. I don't see any other APIs that look like they would allow simulating a two-finger down swipe, for instance.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there isn’t a solution for this until we’re given a specific call for it; the existing gestures are all synchronous so you can’t simulate individual fingers doing different things at the same time.

There are pinch and rotate functions, but they can’t be made to do what you’re looking for.

Comment: Thanks. I guess my only choice may be to add some hack to the app so I can test this functionality. But I am hoping someone will come up with some automated solution eventually, or maybe Apple will give us an API someday.